# Glassfish 4 does not write stacktrace to set log file

Tags: logging, groovy, glassfish, glassfish-4

I am using Glassfish 4.0. I ran

```
asadmin set-log-attributes com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=$MY_LOG_FILE
```

so that Glassfish logs to `$MY_LOG_FILE` and not to `$GLASSFISH_PATH/domains/domain1/logs/server.log` anymore.

I have deployed a basic JavaEE application, written in groovy, that throws an exception.

**My Problem:** All (normal info) messages that Glassfish produces, even System.out.println messages, go to `$MY_LOG_FILE` as expected; except for the stacktrace of the exception thrown. The stacktrace still goes to `$GLASSFISH_PATH/domains/domain1/logs/server.log`.

Why does this happen? I can not figure out why only exceptions still got to the default server.log . How can I log the exceptions to `$MY_LOG_FILE` as well?

Comment: Before downrating, could you tell me what is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an unresolved bug in Glassfish: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20632